# Gradle Spring boot application not executeable after install/uploadArchives

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I want to upload an executable jar/war to a nexus repoistory

When running a gradle build I get a 66 MB jar file containing all required libraries.
However, after running install or uploadArchives, the created jar file now only contains my code and is no long executable.

When creating a war file the only thing missing is Spring's loader package.

Answer (score -1):

The above happens when running gradle tasks separately, 
e.g. `gradle build`
or `gradle install`

However, if the gradle tasks are run together,
e.g. `gradle build install` 
or `gradle build uploadArchives`

the executable part is not removed.